Show the date and time of the latest change in Overleaf
Is there a way to show the date and time of the latest change of the source latex file in Overleaf?
In the desktop environment this can be done through the package filemod, but in Overleaf \filemodprintdate{\jobname} returns 0000/00/00.
Also showing the last person who modified the source could be useful.

welcome! I think this would probably best be addressed to overleaf. if you have a paid account, I believe you may be able to make use of version control and you may be able to get something like the information you want that way. but I'm sceptical anything like this could work for free accounts. (my university subscribes, but only people in certain depts are entitled to use it or I would try what might be possible.)

In Overleaf the jobname is automatically changed to output, which is different from the real filename (unless you call your file output.tex of course). Therefore filemod cannot find it based on the jobname. \filemodprint{realfilename.tex} does work, however from some quick experimentation it seems the files are recreated (probably using some sort of virtual environment setup) when you open an Overleaf project from the list of projects, therefore the date will still be wrong (i.e., it is set to the moment the project was opened).

I have asked Overleaf, and the short answer is that it is not possible. Of course, paid accounts have access to the full history but these information cannot be retrieved and written in the compiled pdf. Too bad.

@Ale Would you like to write an answer? It could be useful for other users, thank you!

Do you have a normal or a paid account?

Overleaf said that it is not possible. Of course, paid accounts have access to the full history but these information cannot be retrieved and written in the compiled pdf. Too bad.
